# Last item covered by bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

So, I have this problem. My last item of recyclerview is covered by my bottom navigation. The bottom navigation is in activity. The recyclerview is in the fragment. I not found the answer.

Here is my fragment layout, which contain the recyclerview

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".PromoFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/promo_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my item layout that I use in recyclerview

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5px">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_pertama"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

               <include layout="@layout/card_promo_layout"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the image of the result from my code

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:paddingBottom="56dp"` to your `Fragment` that contains `RecyclerView` or to the closest parent layout of `RecyclerView`. For example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    tools:context=".PromoFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/promo_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

P.S. 56dp - is the height of `BottomNavigationView` according to Material Design. So value of `paddingBottom` must be the same as the height of `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: Actually, it works. I've used with marginBottom before but not work. Padding is the perfect one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I did fixed it using an item decoration for the RV and offsetting the latest item of the height of the bottom navigation bar (which is usually the same height of the action bar). EG

```
 mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
           @Override
           public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
               int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
               if (position == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
                      outRect.bottom = bottomMargin;
                }
             }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your bottom Navigation into this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/navigationView" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/your_menu" />
```

And change your Layout into `RelativeLayout`

Comment: what's the difference between using framelayout and relativelayout? I think it's the same thought

Comment: Refer [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-RelativeLayout-and-FrameLayout) to get the difference between them

Answer (score 1):

You can use this android:clipToPadding="false" and add the android:paddingBottom="height of the navigation bar" attributes with your RecyclerView

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/promo_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="height of the navigation bar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"/>
```